# asp.net with client side spell check?

Tags: asp.net, spell-checking

whats the best client side spell check utility to use that would integrate well with asp.net/ c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [ASPNetSpell](http://www.aspnetspell.com/) and it works well.

> ASPNetSpell offers International
>   spellchecking for any number of fields
>   and any popular rich HTML control. You
>   can also replace any TextBox with a
>   SpellTextBox with As-You-Type spelling
>   suggestions in all major browsers.